# Problem with Decision Tree Visualization in Weka: sorry there is no instances data for this node

Tags: csv, dataset, weka, decision-tree

I am visualizing a decision tree using Weka, but when I try to press on anywhere in the tree I get the message "Sorry, there is no instances data for this node."

The data in the tree is unclear and appears overlapping.

- I have checked my data and ensured that there are values for all attributes.
- I used J48 as the algorithm to build the tree.

Comment: I don't believe any decision tree fills in the `data` attribute in the DOT graph that they generate. So you will never see any data in there.